# Chain configured Namespaces with two ORM EntityManagers

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7, bundles

I tried to create an application with two bundles / db-connection (one for each db).
DB-Connect works fine (tried with php app/console doctrine:query:sql --connection master/default).
But I always get the error:

```
MappingException in MappingException.php line 37:
The class 'PortalBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain configured 
namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity.
```

Any hints?

config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default

        connections:
          default:
                  ....
          master: 
                  ....
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
            master:
                connection: master
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    PortalBundle: ~
                    MasterBundle: ~

fos_user:
    db_driver:  orm
    firewall_name:  main
    model_manager_name: default
    user_class: PortalBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:  PortalBundle\Entity\UserGroup
```

Comment: Can you show your `PortalBundle\Entity\User` class?

Comment: As a rule, auto mapping does not work well when dealing with multiple entity managers though I don't think that is the problem here.  Consider commenting out the master entity manager and getting things to work first.